# ng-selected not working for angular 1.6.1, but works for 1.3.15

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, select

The following select has the correct `option` pre-selected at `2` in Angular 1.3.15, but not Angular 1.6.1:

```
Selected is {{myNumber}}
<select ng-model="myNumber">
    <option ng-selected="i == myNumber" ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]">
        {{i}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Then in JS:

```
$scope.myNumber = 2;
```

In Angular 1.6.1, the dropdown looks like this: [image]

How do I do this in Angular 1.6.1?

Comment: try considering `ng-options`.

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned in the docs, also there is a issue raised for the same on github,

[`[bug] ngSelected won't select the option within a ngRepeat`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14876)

Alternatively you should use [`ng-options`](https://plnkr.co/edit/ssY4LirNDr5StDuJkPYQ?p=preview)

```
<select ng-model="user.item_id" ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in items">
</select>
```

Comment: Bummer. The "as," "for", and "in" syntax always confused me for the ng-options.

Comment: did the above answer help